# Convert the CST time to local browser time

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2-moment

I am using Moment Js to convert the CST time to local browser time. My data is coming from back-end code is in "America/Chicago" timezone. I want to convert the "America/Chicago" timezone to Browser time. But date is not converted correctly.

Below is the code.

```js
var currentDate = moment.parseZone('2018-10-02 06:30:53').local().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
var currentTime = moment.parseZone('2018-10-02 06:30:53').local().subtract({
  'minutes': 0
}).format('hh:mm A');
console.log(currentDate, currentTime)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.js"></script>
```

Input Date: "2018-10-03 01:46:40" ('america/chicago')

Output Date: "10/03/2018 07:16 AM" (IST time zone)

Expected Output: 10/03/2018 12:16 PM" (IST time zone)

Comment: What is not correctly? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: I created you a snippet. Please provide expected output

Comment: Append 'CST' to the string before converting it to a date in javascript:

`var date = new Date('10/02/2018 06:30:53 PM CST');
date.toString() // "your local date and time"`

Comment: Also no need to create the datetime twice

Comment: I have update the question with Input, output and expected output. Please check it once.

Comment: @mplungjan I need to show the date and time separately in view. thats why I used twice.

Comment: @IgalS. I have update the question.

Comment: @ManeeshRao Sure, but create the moment object once

Comment: I have done same. but not getting expected output.

Comment: Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/eu5p3yso/

Comment: @mplungjan You have converted to "America/chicago" time zone. But I need to convert it on browser timezone. My date is coming from backend "America/chicago" timezone and need to convert local time of any country.

Comment: Create the moment object in the chicago timezone then convert